# Different version of site based on IP (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, ip, multiple-versions

My client has a wordpress site. However for people visiting the site from a UK IP address he wants different information. Some of the differences include code changes, other differences include a change in the nav menu, and change in content.

Im thinking of duplicating the site where a simple redirect occurs based on UK IP address. However the issue with this is having two sites to maintain.

Are there any other relatively simple ways of setting this up? I would prefer not use wordpress multisites as I dont think that will cater for code changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Geoposty](http://wordpress.org/plugins/geoposty/) wordpress plugin determines your visitor's location from their ip address, then displays dynamic content that is spescific to their area.

Many more plugins are also used for geo targeting like [Geo Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geographical-redirect/), [WordPress Geo IP Redirect](http://www.wpjedi.com/georedirect), [Source Redirect Site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/source-redirect-site/), [WP Geocode Marketing Intelligence](http://www.wpgeocode.com) these all are free, There's a premium plugin also for geo targeting named [Flytonic Geo Target](http://www.flytonic.com/plugins/geo-target/)

#### But!!!

If I'm a French user, but my IP shows I'm in Germany while I use an English browser. The most convenient would be English for me, because that is my choice.

There's a PHP superglobal variable, called `$_SERVER`. It stores information about the server running the page and about the client who requested the page. One string of this array's parameters is called `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, sent by the browser, which in this case will be **en**. It can be accessed from PHP as: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.

This can be used to get the specified content for example with a custom field which contains values what this string can be.